# Divide 2 columns with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Requirement:**

Divide EUR exchange rate by USD exchange rate and show result in a new column.
For example, 0.912/0.822 = 1.1.  I want the 1.1 in a new column called 'EUR/USD'

I will have to do this division for a few different rates but we can use the EUR/USD as an example.

**Query**

```
select er.Rate, wc.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc.Descr as [Currency], er.EDate as [Exchange Date], ISNULL(wc.MonSymbol, ' ') AS [Symbol], er2.Rate as [Rate2]
from ExchangeRate er
JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
JOIN ExchangeRate er2 on er.InExchangeRateId = er2.InExchangeRateId
inner join (
    select wc.CurrencyCode, max(er.EDate) as MaxDate
    from ExchangeRate er
    JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
    group by wc.CurrencyCode
) erm on wc.CurrencyCode = erm.CurrencyCode and er.EDate = erm.MaxDate
```

**Current Result**

[image]

[Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2df3a2)

**Attempt**

```
select b.*,max(case when b.currency='EUR Euro' then b.Rate end)/max(case when 

     b.currency='USD US Dollar' then b.Rate end) as [EUR/USD] from

    (select er.Rate as Rate, wc.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc.Descr as [Currency], er.EDate 
    as [Exchange Date], ISNULL(wc.MonSymbol, ' ') AS [Symbol], er2.Rate as [Rate2]
    from ExchangeRate er
    JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
      JOIN ExchangeRate er2 on er.InExchangeRateId = er2.InExchangeRateId
  inner join (
     select wc.CurrencyCode, max(er.EDate) as MaxDate
       from ExchangeRate er
       JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
     group by wc.CurrencyCode
    ) erm on wc.CurrencyCode = erm.CurrencyCode and er.EDate = erm.MaxDate)b
    group by b.rate, b.Currency, b.[Exchange Date], b.Symbol, b.Rate2
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Solution:**

```
select er.Rate, wc.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc.Descr as [Currency], er.EDate as [Exchange Date], ISNULL(wc.MonSymbol, ' ') AS [Symbol],
[eur].Rate/[usd].rate as [EUR/USD], [usd].Rate/[zar].rate as [USD/ZAR], [eur].Rate/[zar].rate as [EUR/ZAR], [eur].Rate/[nok].rate as [EUR/NOK],
[eur].Rate/[bwp].rate as [EUR/BWP], [bwp].Rate/[zar].rate as [ZAR/BWP]
from ExchangeRate er
JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
inner join (
    select wc.CurrencyCode, max(er.EDate) as MaxDate
    from ExchangeRate er
    JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
    group by wc.CurrencyCode
) erm on wc.CurrencyCode = erm.CurrencyCode and er.EDate = erm.MaxDate
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT er3.Rate, wc3.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc3.Descr as [Currency], er3.EDate as [Exchange Date]
FROM ExchangeRate er3
JOIN WorldCurrency wc3 on er3.ExCurrencyId = WC3.InCurrencyId
WHERE wc3.CurrencyCode = 'USD' AND er3.EDate = erm.MaxDate) as [USD]

OUTER APPLY
(SELECT er4.Rate, wc4.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc4.Descr as [Currency], er4.EDate as [Exchange Date]
FROM ExchangeRate er4
JOIN WorldCurrency wc4 on er4.ExCurrencyId = WC4.InCurrencyId
WHERE wc4.CurrencyCode = 'EUR' AND er4.EDate = erm.MaxDate) as [EUR]

OUTER APPLY
(SELECT er5.Rate, wc5.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc5.Descr as [Currency], er5.EDate as [Exchange Date]
FROM ExchangeRate er5
JOIN WorldCurrency wc5 on er5.ExCurrencyId = WC5.InCurrencyId
WHERE wc5.CurrencyCode = 'ZAR' AND er5.EDate = erm.MaxDate) as [ZAR]

OUTER APPLY
(SELECT er6.Rate, wc6.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc6.Descr as [Currency], er6.EDate as [Exchange Date]
FROM ExchangeRate er6
JOIN WorldCurrency wc6 on er6.ExCurrencyId = WC6.InCurrencyId
WHERE wc6.CurrencyCode = 'NOK' AND er6.EDate = erm.MaxDate) as [NOK]

OUTER APPLY
(SELECT er7.Rate, wc7.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc7.Descr as [Currency], er7.EDate as [Exchange Date]
FROM ExchangeRate er7
JOIN WorldCurrency wc7 on er7.ExCurrencyId = WC7.InCurrencyId
WHERE wc7.CurrencyCode = 'BWP' AND er7.EDate = erm.MaxDate

) as [BWP]
```

Comment: **Consumable** sample data and expected results will help us help you/ What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: It would be nice if you could give example of data contained in individual tables(ex: WorldCurrency). It helps to reproduce the task and answer very quickly.

Comment: The above is what I tried so far and the current result that I am getting.  Requirement title explains my expected result. What I need to do is divide rate where currency is EUR by rate where currency is USD..

Comment: What table is providing the usd/eur pairing? Please post definitions of your tables and example data, preferably as a sql fiddle?

Comment: The problem you've got is that usd and eur are on different rows; you need a table that links them together. Why is usd/eur a pair and usd/nok not a pair? Or maybe it is a pair. That's why we need to know what pairs your company wants to trade between. No one trades all world pairs. Sometimes trades have to go into another currency that is common between the pairs eg nok->eur->usd

Comment: Is that is your result set after your attempt, that doesn't help us at all. What we *need* is the data **before** your query and the results you want. We cab't tell you have to get "from A to B" when the only location we have it C, and no information of what A or B are.

Comment: Please see updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Posted solution above that worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    select b.*,case when b.currency='EUR Euro' then b.Rate end/case when 

     b.currency='USD US Dollar' then b.Rate end as [EUR/USD] from

    (select er.Rate as Rate, wc.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc.Descr as [Currency], er.EDate 
    as [Exchange Date], ISNULL(wc.MonSymbol, ' ') AS [Symbol], er2.Rate as [Rate2]
    from ExchangeRate er
    JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
      JOIN ExchangeRate er2 on er.InExchangeRateId = er2.InExchangeRateId
  inner join (
     select wc.CurrencyCode, max(er.EDate) as MaxDate
       from ExchangeRate er
       JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
     group by wc.CurrencyCode
    ) erm on wc.CurrencyCode = erm.CurrencyCode and er.EDate = erm.MaxDate)b
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it did not work.  Got NULL results in the EUR/USD column but it did give me an idea.  Let me try it and will report how I get on.

Comment: i don't have your sample data but i think using aggregate function like min or max will solve your problem . max(case when b.currency='EUR Euro' then b.Rate end)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would like to do this and this is a longshot without knowing the ExchangeRate table. But this should do what you're asking

```
select er.Rate, 
wc.CurrencyCode + ' ' + wc.Descr as [Currency], 
er.EDate as [Exchange Date], ISNULL(wc.MonSymbol, ' ') AS [Symbol], 
er2.Rate as [Rate2],

erEur.Rate/erUsd.Rate as [EUR/USD]

from ExchangeRate er
JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
JOIN ExchangeRate er2 on er.InExchangeRateId = er2.InExchangeRateId
JOIN ExchangeRate erUsd on er.EDate = erEUR.Edate and erEUR.CurrencyCode = 'USD'
JOIN ExchangeRate erEur on er.EDate = erEUR.Edate and erEUR.CurrencyCode = 'EUR'
inner join (
    select wc.CurrencyCode, max(er.EDate) as MaxDate
    from ExchangeRate er
    JOIN WorldCurrency wc on er.ExCurrencyId = WC.InCurrencyId
    group by wc.CurrencyCode
) erm on wc.CurrencyCode = erm.CurrencyCode and er.EDate = erm.MaxDate
```